# IonContent not rendering under IonicPage. React. No error

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

**EDIT: I believe the reason that I ran into this problem is I didn't use the ionic start command to create my project and because I didn't have the Ionic CDN in my HTML file.**

I hope I can explain this issue I'm having in a clean and concise way.

## Environment Information

I am currently using Ionic 6 with React 18

And here are my Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ionic/react": "^6.1.2",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^6.1.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.27",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "dart-sass": "^1.25.0",
    "node": "16.14.2",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router": "^5.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.2",
    "testcafe-react-selectors": "^4.1.5",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "17.0.24",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.1",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.18",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.19.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "testcafe": "^1.18.6",
    "typescript": "4.6.3",
    "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^3.4.0"
},
```

## Goal

I want to be able to have an Ionic React multi-page application. Obviously it will still be  a SPA and not actually have different pages but I want to utilize Ionic's [IonPage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation#ionpage) component which creates a new React View that can be navigated to.

## Expected Results

I've stripped much of my project to just bare bones components that I want to be able to use to create a side navigation and be able to navigate to each page and see the contents. Currently I'm just trying to get the ability to see everything from a React Component wrapped in IonPage. This is my App.tsx page:

### App.tsx

```
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet, setupIonicReact } from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Home from './components/Home';
import './custom.css';

setupIonicReact({
    mode: 'md',
});

function App() {
    return (
        <IonApp>
            <IonReactRouter>
                <IonRouterOutlet>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
                </IonRouterOutlet>
            </IonReactRouter>
        </IonApp>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I've tried a variety of layouts for my Home.tsx file. Currently this is what is inside

## First situation

### Home.tsx Current Version

```
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage } from '@ionic/react';
import React from 'react';

const Home: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonHeader>Example</IonHeader>
            <IonContent fullscreen> 
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

With this setup, the Example Header text shows and is styled like a header correctly. However, the Content Text doesn't show up at all on this. I've determined the reason why it doesn't show up is because the ion-content element/component's height is set to 0.  This is not expected. We don't have any css in our project targeting ion-content elements.

## Second situation

```
import { IonContent, IonPage } from '@ionic/react';
import React from 'react';

const Home: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonContent fullscreen>
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

In this situation I expect the elements inside of the IonContent Component to be rendered. I originally didn't have the 'fullscreen' attribute but added it recently to test if it was different. It didn't have an affect. What the result is is a completely blank page with the ion-page having width of 0 as well as the ion-content having a width of 0. If I set the widths of the ion-page manually it appears the ion-content's width and height update as well and it shows the content I was looing for.

## Third Situation

```
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/react';
import React from 'react';

const Home: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <IonContent fullscreen>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </IonContent>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

In this situation I've removed the IonPage element from the page. Surprisingly it appears that the content is displayed in this situation even though I've seen online that the IonRouter need to find an element with IonPage.

## What I want to achieve:

I want to be able to have a react component with IonPage, IonHeader, and IonContent and have all elements inside of these render on the page when navigated to it.

## What I want to know

What is causing the IonPage to behave strangely by having 0 height at some points. Why does the Content not show when wrapped around an IonPage but an IonHeader wrapped around an IonPage does show.

## No Error Messages Available

## Additional Notes

I also attempted to create a new IonicProject with react 17 instead of 18 as I thought it was a support issue, but it appears with the same full code with IonPage, IonContent, and IonHeader the content was not displaying. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I basically created a sidenav template from ionic start and determined all of the differences between the two projects.

I eventually determined that there are additional css import statements that I didn't realize I needed to add to my App.tsx in order for the IonApp,IonHeader,IonContent to work correctly.

These are the imports I found from the template project:

```
/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import "@ionic/react/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import "@ionic/react/css/normalize.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/structure.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/typography.css";

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import "@ionic/react/css/padding.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css";
import "@ionic/react/css/display.css";

/* Theme variables */
import "./theme/variables.css";
```

The theme variables are option and if there isn't a variables.css file in the theme folder it will give an error.

However after adding these import statements all of the content on the page renders.

Answer (score 1):

```
import "@ionic/react/css/core.css";
```

Importing this helped for me i wasn't seeing anything inside my `IonContent` but can anyone explain why this happened.